# Decrypting a json dictionary to be altered Python

Tags: python, json, database, encryption, filter

I am trying to do a symmetrical decryption to the `sample.json` file below. The `key` is the password to which the json file can be decrypted by. I want to decrypt the message below and then turn the decrypted message `decrypted_data` into a dictionary and replace the `BTCUSD` symbol with `ETHUSD` with the `RSI` folder. However I get an error `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`. I am trying to typecast `bytes` into a dictionary format. How would I be able to do that?

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = bytes(b'OKdXZnSshhlEZ6w44b0I366BZN5mb5sZQRHp5-UsCfo=')
filename = 'sample.json'

def decrypt(key, filename):
    """
    Given a filename (str) and key (bytes), it decrypts the file and write it
    """
    keyval = Fernet(key)
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        # read the encrypted data
        encrypted_data = f.read()
    # decrypt data
    decrypted_data = dict(keyval.decrypt(encrypted_data))
    decrypted_data['RSI'][0]['TradingPair'] = 'ETHUSD'

decrypt(key, filename)
```

Encrypted Json file:

```
gAAAAABhHBuLjIIKNHOLC2PcTHUhzbLM20XavWaQZjRK0oIwWOhni_LOogN6emtbpfPCNPx1TrZJv4Op0BnqTq_Xl-TXCPdSl7_83HEuyRfBEh_VX5zLA1AS9fEocO4_CB7OYeC2Id_PuxZBreaPlzGuHi0uDwIhnYSigVUIPWRa4g9Dp4_rSHSQJxNIbr_VqwUIBP1ComtMieU1prsSib_L2y-5xZqxh7gDAWGRekKEZefiuk3BNhboiEW_0oDYph3bpCV305t8O4-cHLer91ebme7XCfC75H_w7yyylR5QHf0MPVrJUt8fkuRd1vU7hsLD3x16KViCepZnE5YFjA6vXrsRJsciPccAg5rXLJi7qz-jnfZCCJI=
```

Decrypted Json file

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "Status": "ACTIVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: To parse JSON out of a string, use `json.loads(json_string)`, not `dict(json_string)`. You may also need to call decode to convert bytes to a string, as in `json.loads(keyval.decrypt(encrypted_data).decode("utf-8"))`.

Comment: Is there anyway I could revert it back to the `bytes ` format? I am trying to make it write the encrypted json data back to the file.

Comment: Using `json.dumps` and `str.encode`?